# Angular 12 error NG8001 - 'mi componente' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, module.exports

Hola estoy viendo que hay muchos temas con mi error de compilación en Angular 12, pero ninguno parece que es como mi caso, he creado un componente en la raíz de mi proyecto en /app, un spinner, dicho componente está declarado en app.module.ts, y yo quiero usar el selector de ese componente `<app-spinner>` en **otro** componente llamado register, que está en /app/public/autentificacion/register, en la carpeta /autentificacion tengo un módulo llamado autentificacion.module, y en la carpeta de public otro llamado public.module.ts, estos son los archivos

**autentificacion.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/private/pages/home/home.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { InicioComponent } from './pages/inicio/inicio.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    InicioComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSnackBarModule
  ]
})
export class AutentificacionModule { }
```

**public.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AutentificacionModule } from './autentificacion/autentificacion.module';
import { PageErrorComponent } from './page-error/page-error.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AutentificacionModule
  ]
})
export class PublicModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { PublicModule } from './public/public.module';
import { PrivateModule } from './private/private.module';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './spinner/spinner.component';
import { AutentificacionModule } from './public/autentificacion/autentificacion.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SpinnerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PublicModule,
    PrivateModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatIconModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    SpinnerComponent //He intentado exportar este componente aquí pero parece que no da resultado
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

el error que me tira es el siguiente de la captura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese error lo da al intentar hacer en mi register.component.html

```
 <div class="campo campoBoton">
      <app-spinner *ngIf="showSpinner"></app-spinner>  **<----Este línea!**
      <button (click)="onSubmit($event)" type="submit" class="botonSubmit">Registrarme</button>
      <button (click)="closeModal()" type="button" class="botonSubmit">
        Volver
      </button>
    </div>
```

He intentado importar/exportar en todos lados, reiniciar el servidor, volver a compilarlo con ng serve y ng serve -o pero nada, se os ocurre algo? o veis algo que me pueda faltar?

Un saludo!

Comment: Importa el SpinnerComponent en el AuthModule. Ahora bien si eso no funciona podrías empezar por meter todas las importaciones de Material en su propio modulo para ir organizando, tal vez poner el Spinner y el ErrorComponent en un SharedModule (o si quieres reutilizar el PublicModule), e importar directamente el AuthModule y Shared(o Public) al AppModule.

Comment: Hice un shared module, importé el authmodule e hice un export del spinner component, luego ya es importar shared module donde lo necesite y listo, ha costado pero solucionado!

Comment: @JuanJesúsSedanoCalderón En general en cada modulo que necesites importar un componente de Material importas su modulo contenedor.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta importar el componente **SpinnerComponent** unicamente en tu **autentificacion.module.ts**

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).